# Python 2.7 : How to use BeautifulSoup in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup

I am trying to to following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

and got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py", line 355, in post
    exec(compiled_code, globals())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

How can I use it with `Google App Engine runtime 2.7`?

**Update**
My project structure looks like

```
flask-appengine-template/
                        docs/
                        licenses/
                        src/
                            application/
                                        static/
                                        templates/
                                        models.py
                                        settings.py
                                        urls.py
                                        views.py
                        libs/
                            bs4/
                         app.yaml
                         src.py
```

I am using this template from [here](https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template)
Since parent of `app.yaml` is `src`, I added a file `src.py` and added two lines there.

I still see the same error

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

However, my project name as per `app.yaml` is `flaskonappengine`
Please tell me what is I am still doing wrong?

Comment: have you added the `bs4` module inside app's folder? BeautifulSoup is not included as a supported library. it is necessary to load it with the application.

Comment: do I have do do this with any other library which is not part of GAE?

Comment: except this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27, yes.

Comment: you can go through http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Comment: GAE support only [Pure Python Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_Pure_Python). The bs4 is not pure bcos its some parts were written in C. But, its old version was written purely in Python. So, You just download [BeautifulSoup 3.2.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup) then extract the BeautifulSoup.py file from it.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to use 3rd party libraries that are not included [this list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27), then you'll have to add them manually.

In order to include manually any other library you have to have them inside the directory where the `app.yaml` lives. So for example if you have the following structure:

```
hello
├── libs
│   └── bs4 
├── hello.py 
└── app.yaml
```

then in your `hello.py` you have to put these two lines in the beginning of the file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')
```

After doing that you'll be able to use any 3rd party library that you're going to put in that `libs` directory. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

### Update

Since you're using that framework, rollback your changes and use the same pattern as they are using for flask or werkzeug or other 3rd party libraries. Just put the bs4 in the src directory and try to include it normally.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it did not work, I added the update, please help

Comment: @daydreamer I updated my answer, if you managed to make it work before all these changes, then it should be easy to include it just in the src as I wrote in the answer..

Comment: @daydreamer Did that work after all?! If it did would be nice to be accepted because it keeps popping up..

Comment: @Lipis : I follow your guide, but i still get the error. Could you please see the capture: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27576887/1.JPG

Comment: yes.. libs is a string.. not a variable.. 'libs'