# How to include third party Python libraries in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How to add third party python libraries in Google App Engine, which are not provided by Google? I am trying  to use BeautifulSoup in Google App Engine and unable to do so. But my question is for any library I want to use in Google App Engine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I manage third-party Python libraries with Google App Engine? (virtualenv? pip?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv)

Comment: I just posted an updated answer to the OP question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67863189/305689

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Actually I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648038/8418) fits better here.

If you want to use 3rd party libraries that are not included in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648038/8418), then you'll have to add them manually.

In order to include manually any other library you have to have them inside the directory where the `app.yaml` lives. So for example if you have the following structure:

```
hello
├── libs
│   └── bs4 
├── hello.py 
└── app.yaml
```

then in your `hello.py` you have to put these two lines in the beginning of the file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')
```

After doing that you'll be able to use any 3rd party library that you're going to put in that `libs` directory.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: I am still having problems with this after following the directions. Has anything changed with GAE?

Comment: The answer from Jesse is much better IMHO.

Answer (score 58):

Google has provided a documented way for included third-party libraries in your GAE project.

See the ["Adding Third-party Packages to the Application" section of the Libraries in Python 2.7 docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring).

> If you want to include additional pure-python third-party packages, you can do so by setting up vendoring. Vendoring allows you to install packages to a subdirectory of your project and include them in your code. To use vendoring, create (or modify) **appengine_config.py** in the root of your project.

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

And then just put all your libs' source code in your `lib` dir

```
> pip install beautifulsoup4 -t lib
```

So your project directory structure looks like this:

```
project
- lib
  - bs4
- your_code.py
```

This will allow your project's source files to import libs' packages/modules as if they were added to your `PYTHON_PATH`. For example:

```
# file: your_code.py
import bs4  # no need for 'from lib import bs4'
# do stuff with bs4...
```

You can also easily install everything from a requirements.txt file by doing the following command

```
> pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: This answer seems to be better then the one that is accepted. Thanks Jesse!

Comment: this worked for me for a long time, but just began failing inexplicably. I am now getting 'virtualenv: cannot access lib: No such virtualenv or site directory'

Comment: @bgenchel @PrestonCrawford Were either of you able to resolve your problems? I have never seen that `virtualenv` error and this approach is still currently working for me. If you still haven't solved it, please post a new question and link it here and I will try to help. Make sure to add many details.

Comment: What happened for me, I think, was that I was trying to import from lib as a package, not understanding that vendor.add("lib") means you can access libraries inside as though they were on your python path. The error was thrown because after running the pip install on my requirements file, I had forgotten to put an __init__.py inside the folder. Thanks for offering!!

Comment: I was and I wasn't. I'm only getting the error through PyCharm right now. Trying to sort that out.

Comment: this is so frustating. not working for me, followed all steps but nope

Comment: @JesseWebb I followed all the steps and my app still cannot access the package I've placed in lib/ when it's deployed. Any chance you know something that I don't?

Answer (score 3):

You simply copy the folder containing the library you want to use into your app engine project.

Then when you deploy it's uploaded with your application and is available for use.

EDIT: [Jesse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29681061/346561) is how I now do this. So do that!

Answer (score 1):

The way it worked here is:

```
import sys
# sys.path.insert(0, 'libs') #"Old" way, not working for me.
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "libs")) # This works!
```

Then import normally:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put Beautifulsoup in the root of your project and upload it all

Comment: Can i put it in some specific folder like - 'lib'?

Comment: yes manipulate sys.path or use site module as in `site.addsitedir('lib')

Answer (score 0):

pip install -t lib package_name

**lib**: *the location for third party libraries*

Then you are good to use this package like a normal library you use from ipython or terminal.