# How to disable Google App Engine python SDK import hook?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am playing around with local deployment of GAE python SDK. The code that I am trying to run contains many external libraries which are not part of GAE import whitelist. I want to disable the import restrictions and let GAE app import any locally installed module.

After walking through the code, I figured out that they use custom **import hooks** for restricting imports. However, I have not been able to figure out how to disable the overridden import hook.

Let me know if you have any idea how this can be accomplished.

Comment: If I understood correctly you simply want to include 3rd party libraries.. correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include third party python libs in google appengine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libs-in-google-appengine)

Comment: I have lot of third party libraries used in my code and its practically impossible for me to whitelist all of them. Here, I just want to remove the check which I think would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing is to modify google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py and add the module you want to the whitelist.

This will allow you to import whatever you want.

Now there's a good reason that the imports are restricted in the development server.  The restricted imports match what's available on the production environment.  So if you add libraries to the whitelist, your code may run on your local development server, but it will not run on the production environment.

And no, you can't import restricted modules on production.

Comment: This code is part of a research project and would not be used in production. I know about whitelisting modules but considering that my code is dependent on many third party libraries it's practically impossible for me to whitelist them individually.

Comment: You can find the code in the SDK that searches through the whitelist, and modify it to whitelist everything.  It's in the same file.

Comment: Modifying just the check in the whitelist only won't work because the check is_file_accessible will fail. I commented out that check as well but I have run into some other problem now. I will post an update as soon as I manage to solve this problem.