# ImportError: No module named endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am not able to import the module `endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb` while using Endpoints API with Python. Is anybody facing similar issue? Please let me know what could be the problem.

I am using Google App Engine SDK 1.7.5 for Python.

Comment: I'm the author of `endpoints-proto-datastore`. Is there a document, presentation or slide deck you were referencing that suggested you import from `endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb`?

Comment: I was following the Vedio available in Youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wNRUd9E1jM Appengine : cloud endpoints part II.

Comment: Great to hear! If you jump ahead to 7 minutes in, I describe how to include the library in your project.

Comment: I downloaded library but missed to copy , I did it now and its working Thanks @bossylobster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using a 3rd party library since the `endpoints_proto_datastore` is not part of the core App Engine SDK.

In short you will have to include this library in your project and then making sure that is in the path. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14851686/8418) for more details.

Comment: Correct. It can be downloaded here: https://code.google.com/p/endpoints-proto-datastore/

Comment: Correct http://code.google.com/p/endpoints-proto-datastore/source/browse/#git%2Fendpoints_proto_datastore%253Fstate%253Dclosed i included endpoints_proto_datastore it works for me . Thanks