# How to implement WSGIProxy using setuptools in python google app engine for a webapp

Tags: python, google-app-engine, setuptools, django-wsgi

Can somebody explain me how to use the [setuptools](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) inside python in google app engine to implement [WSGIProxy](http://pythonpaste.org/wsgiproxy/) for a webapp.

How do i utilize it, if i dont  have access to the filesystem? Specifically,easy steps on how install package from python egg on GAE.

This should be relatively easy for someone who has used setuptools or installed 3rd party packages on GAE python.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered almost the same question, but about a different library.  The concept behind installing thirdparty libraries is exactly the same though, you need to either put a copy of the actual code in your app folder, or use a softlink to in.

[GAE - Including external python modules without adding them to the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651891/gae-including-external-python-modules-without-adding-them-to-the-repository/15653005#15653005)

Comment: Agreed, I normally use virtualenv --no-site-packages to install 3rd party libs into the dir above, and then use symlinks in the actual project dir lib folder.  Ie I have a project directory and the actual appengine project sits under that.