# How to solving ImportError: No module named scraping

Tags: google-app-engine

This is rj.
I have question about google web engine for python.
When I deploy my scraping source code, following error was occurred. 
Please help me to solve this problem. Error code follows,

```
ERROR    2016-05-25 01:13:25,282 wsgi.py:263] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler

    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject

    obj = __import__(path[0])

ImportError: No module named scraping_ert_v1
```

INFO     2016-05-25 10:13:25,289 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: Looks like you need to check your dependencies. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651891/gae-including-external-python-modules-without-adding-them-to-the-repository) might help you.