# Unsupported python libraries in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I've tried to find the answer to this question but couldn't determine if adding Python libraries unsupported by Google App Engine is possible somehow or not at all.

My Python program was not meant to be a Google App but now I would like to it to be.

It is a very big project with thousands of lines of code and uses many libraries which are not on the [list of supported libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/libraries).

The first Error I get and the stack-trace:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo_includes.py", line 63, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo.py", line 1690, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 226, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: the library "gspread" is not supported
```

This will probably be the same for other libraries such as: Igraph, cairo, etc...

Is there a simple way around this issue or must I give up on deploying my program to Google?

Comment: A pure Python library can be uploaded along with your code, but a library that uses C extensions (that are not optional) is probably not going to work unless Google has specifically made it available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include third party python libs in google appengine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libs-in-google-appengine)

Comment: The first answer there basically answers your question

Comment: +1, Indeed. Somehow my search didn't return this. Even though the answer is kind of the one down here and the question is similar I do think the approach is different since here I crashed in the issue posting error message as well so I will leave this question here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to list `gspread` in the `libraries` section of your `app.yaml` file. First of all, that's not what that section is for. Read about it in the docs.

Second, the way to get third-party libraries into your app is to ship them with your app, just like the rest of your app's code. This is what you should do. You just have to make sure that

1. Python can find your third-party libraries
2. the libraries are pure Python; no C modules.

Comment: Yes. Even though this is the answer to my question I will need to look for other ways because I also have a wx GUI. I'm far from doing well with GAE. Thanks.

Comment: How would wx be able to show a desktop window in any Web app? Seems like that would prevent you from serving your app no matter what platform you serve it from.

Comment: Yes. That's what I said. Will need to remake everything.