# Networkx on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, networkx

Is it possible to use Networkx on Google App Engine? I don't need to plot the graph. I just need to use the graph data structure and some algorithms from Networkx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the Networkx library inside a folder (say lib) inside the folder where app.yaml resides. Then in the same folder (as app.yaml), add the following lines in appengine_config.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')
```

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libs-in-google-appengine/14851686#14851686).