# Why is my Python App Engine app using the Translate API getting an error of ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-translate, google-api-python-client, google-translation-api

I got this error in **Google App Engine's Python** have used Google Translate API,
But I don't know how to fix,

```
<module>
from apiclient.discovery import build
ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery
```

I'll try to **set environment which indicates to Google App Engine SDK**,
And upload to Google Apps Engine again, **always get the error**,

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
> If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you include `apiclient` code directory in your appengine project ?

Comment: do you mean the External Libraries? (It's the /Google App Engine SDK/ google-api-python-client/apiclient/discovery.py)? I use IDEA IntelliJ. Thanks for providing more information

Comment: Make sure you are not running your program as sudo because pip install libs at your user home, then root user doesn't have these libraries `pip show PyDrive`

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/ may help with the process

Comment: This was the first page I hit, but I missed the answers below initially from Nijin and Varun. You need to include the module in the app working directory as a 'third party package' following instructions from the link. On Linux Ubuntu, I also had to use sudo when using the -t switch to install to lib/.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

You should be able to get these dependencies with this simple install:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

This is described on the [quick start page for python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started).

Comment: I encounter the same error after doing just that. Well I installed it with `C:\>C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py --upgrade google-api-python-client`
and it says `Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\google_api_python_client-1.3.1-py2.7.egg` and trying to install again `google-api-python-client 1.3.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth`

Comment: The link provided in the answer moved to [Googles Getting Started with Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started)

Comment: I have no idea, why the above command without `sudo` worked for me.

Comment: For Python 3, pip needs to replaced with pip3 in the above command. It might not be obvious for some I believe.

Comment: Using Debian 9 Stretch I used the command `sudo apt-get install python-googleapi python-oauth2client` and the command `sudo apt-get install python3-googleapi python3-oauth2client`. It worked perfect and I prefer this way because I have enough with one package manager.

Comment: It's bad practice and potentially very dangerous to use sudo with pip. If you don't need sudo, don't use it.

Answer (score 176):

`apiclient` was the original name of the library.
At some point, it was switched over to be `googleapiclient`.

If your code is running on Google App Engine, both should work.

If you are running the application yourself, with the [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) installed, both should work as well.

Although, if we take a look at [the source code of the `apiclient` package's `__init__.py` module](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/apiclient/__init__.py#L1), we can see that the `apiclient` module was simply kept around for backwards-compatibility.

> Retain apiclient as an alias for googleapiclient.

So, you really should be using `googleapiclient` in your code, since the `apiclient` alias was just maintained as to not break legacy code.

```
# bad
from apiclient.discovery import build

# good
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

Comment: More information: I just had this problem (Python 3.5.2), and changing the name in the `import` statement fixed it. I had moved Google's sample code into a file in PyCharm, and when PyCharm prompted me to install a package named `apiclient` I did so. When I actually looked at the module it had installed, it was tiny and didn't seem to be related to Google.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Have been using apiclient in python 2 for sometime, just created a new project in Pycharm (moving across to Python3 for all new projects) and simply changing from apliclient to googleapliclient (ensuring it was installed) fixed and allowed my basic template framework for reporting to carry forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

If none of the above solutions work for you, consider if you might have installed python through Anaconda. If this is the case then installing the google API library with conda might fix it.

Run:

```
python --version
```

If you get something like

```
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Then try:

```
conda install google-api-python-client
```

As bgoodr has pointed out in a comment you might need to specify the channel (think repository) to get the google API library. At the time of writing this means running the command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge google-api-python-client
```

See more at https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/google-api-python-client

Comment: Actually a channel is needed apparently. See https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/google-api-python-client  (see the -c option).

Comment: Thank you @bgoodr. I have incorporated your comment in the answer.

Comment: After providing the channel, it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: running python with the version flag didn't bring up 'anaconda', but my VS code environment is set to Conda.  Used the conda install command with the -c parameter and it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

`apiclient` is not in the list of third party library supplied by the appengine runtime: http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27 .

You need to copy `apiclient` into your project directory & you need to copy these `uritemplate` & `httplib2` too.

Note: Any third party library that are not supplied in the documentation list must copy to your appengine project directory

Comment: I used Google Translate API's Python, therefore, I need : apiclient, gflags, httplib2, oauth2client, uritemplate. Thanks :D

Comment: Jorvis' reply is more relevant for those who aren't running application. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Is this really true that apiclient isn't included in the default libraries? WE can see apiclient as a directory listed right in the Google App Engine SDK directory in PyCharm.  That said, even though we see it there, we are still getting the error int his question.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed the problem by reinstalling the package with:

```
pip install --force-reinstall google-api-python-client
```

Comment: Nothing worked for me, except this one!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you only have `google-api-python-client` installed. If you have `apiclient` installed, it will cause a collision. So, run the following:

```
sudo pip uninstall apiclient
```

Answer (score 6):

For app engine project you gotta install the lib locally by typing

```
pip install -t lib google-api-python-client
```

read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)

Comment: This got me working, though I did have to follow the answer here as well to add the lib directory as a vendor: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29681061/1024735

Answer (score 5):

There is a download for the Google API Python Client library that contains the library and all of its dependencies, named something like [google-api-python-client-gae-<version>.zip](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/list) in the downloads section of the project. Just unzip this into your App Engine project.

Answer (score 5):

for python3 this worked for me:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem because of a bug in the installation of the URITemplate module.

This solved the problem:

```
pip install --force-reinstall uritemplate.py
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this same error when working on a project to parse recent calendar events from Google Calendar.

**Using the standard install with pip did not work for me, here is what I did to get the packages I needed.**

Go directly to the source, here is a link for the **google-api-python-client**, but if you need a different language it should not be too different.

https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client

Click on the green "Clone or Download" button near the top left and save it as a zip file. Move the zip to your project folder and extract it there. Then cut all the files from the folder it creates back into the root of your project folder.

Yes, this does clutter your work space, but many compilers have ways to hide files.

After doing this the standard

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
```

works great.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I installed `google-api-python-client`  using **pip** but it is still showing me error so I try upgrading it and it help me to get out of error

if you are using "**windows**" then

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

will help you because it help me so it will help you too :)

Answer (score 3):

"google-api-python-client" requires:

```
pip install uritemplate.py
```

to fix problem on GAE Development Server:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

ImportError: No module named googleapiclient.discovery
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. 
This worked:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.require("google-api-python-client")
[google-api-python-client 1.5.3 (c:\python27), uritemplate 0.6 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages\uritemplate-0.6-py2.7.egg), six 1.10.0 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg), oauth2client 3.0.0 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client-3.0.0-py2.7.egg), httplib2 0.9.2 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg), simplejson 3.8.2 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson-3.8.2-py2.7-win32.egg), six 1.10.0 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg), rsa 3.4.2 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages\rsa-3.4.2-py2.7.egg), pyasn1-modules 0.0.8 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyasn1_modules-0.0.8-py2.7.egg), pyasn1 0.1.9 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.7.egg)]

>>> from apiclient.discovery import build
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It only worked with me when I used sudo:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, even after following Google's guide at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python, then I realized I had to invoke like this:

```
python3 quickstart.py
```

Instead of:

```
python quickstart.py <-- WRONG
```

(Note the "`3`")

Worked flawlessly.

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```

Answer (score 0):

The same error can be seen if you are creating a Python module and your executing the script after installing it via `pip` or `pipx` command.
In this case ensure you have declared what the project **minimally** needs to run correctly into `install_requires` section of your `setup.py` file, so in this case:

```
install_requires=[
    "google-api-python-client>=1.12.3",
    "google-auth-httplib2>=0.0.4",
    "google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if the interpreter on your IDE is pointing to the wrong virtual environment. In VSCODE I've set it manually to the correct interpreter and my problem was solved.

Comment: The same error can be caused by multiple different problems. It's useful to keep alternative answers, like this one, that can help someone else with this variant of the problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**(May 2021)** It's been about 8 years since the original question, and since then, several product changes have occurred, so new developers arriving here looking to use the Google Translate API on Python App Engine have a few changes to make:

1. **Product info/costs**: The Google Translate API is now available as the [Google Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate). It's not free (meaning you need to create a billing account backed by a financial instrument like a credit card), but you get a quota of translated characters per month. See [its pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing) for more info. Similarly, while you used to be able to create an App Engine app *without* a credit card, you can no longer do so via the [new policy as of Nov 2019](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/payment-instrument). It still has a generous ["Always Free" tier quota](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits) which you must exceed in order to incur charges. Also see the [App Engine pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) for more info.
2. **Client libraries**: Rather than using `apiclient` or `googleapiclient` which are part of the [Google APIs client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library) which is a low-level, multi-product, *platform*-level client library, we recommend the [Google Cloud client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries) which are higher-level and *product*-focused. That means there's a specific Cloud Translation client library (actually two: [basic/v2/Python 2](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/python) or [advanced/v3/Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v3/python)) — these are higher-level and much easier to use:

- Add client lib: `pip install -U pip google-cloud-translate` (or `pip3`)
- With it, your code sample can be as simple as:

```
'translate_demo.py - demo the Cloud Translation API'
from __future__ import print_function
import google.auth
from google.cloud import translate

TRANSLATE = translate.TranslationServiceClient()
_, PROJECT_ID = google.auth.default()
PARENT = 'projects/{}'.format(PROJECT_ID)
TARGET_LANG = 'es'
TEXT = 'Hello world'
DATA = {
    'parent': PARENT,
    'contents': [TEXT],
    'target_language_code': TARGET_LANG,
}
try:                # Python 3/advanced/v3
    rsp = TRANSLATE.translate_text(request=DATA)
except TypeError:   # Python 2/basic/v2
    rsp = TRANSLATE.translate_text(**DATA)
print(TEXT, '=', rsp.translations[0].translated_text)
```

It also works on Python 2 and 3 without any modification:

```
$ python2 translate_demo.py
Hello world = Hola Mundo
$ python3 translate_demo.py
Hello world = Hola Mundo
```

This code snippet can be adapted for App Engine fairly easily (more below), especially if you're prototyping since you can take advantage of the [default service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/service-account) so you don't have to muck around with service accounts, like making a new one, creating a public/private key-pair, and having to download the JSON credentials file and pointing the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to it, etc. When you're ready to go into production and need to create your own service account, then check out [this page in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

Furthermore, there has been significant changes in App Engine itself: the original Python 2 App Engine service had a bunch of built-in proprietary APIs (Datastore, Memcache, Task Queues, etc.). Due to user feedback regarding "vendor lock-in," the next generation Python 3 App Engine service was made to free developers from those services. Instead, you'd leverage any equivalent productized services, i.e., [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore), [Cloud Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore), and [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) instead. The Google Cloud team has created a [migration guide](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3) and I've augmented that guide with [hands-on tutorials, code samples, and videos](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/migrate-python2-appengine) to help folks migrate to these unbundled services as you port your app to Python 3.

If you're considering [Google Cloud serverless compute platforms](https://cloud.google.com/serverless#serverless-products) *beyond* App Engine, such as [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) (FaaS) or [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) (containerized/managed CaaS), then check out [this Translation API sample app I created](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/cloud-nebulous-serverless-python) (where I basically stole the above code snippet from) that can be deployed 8 different ways, Python 2 and 3, locally with Flask's development server, to App Engine, Cloud Functions, or Cloud Run, all with just minor config changes. It's meant to show flexibility in our platforms as well as to help users understand the differences between them better.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the module inside the python scripts folder with cmd solved my issue. It seems there was an conflict of anaconda and Python standard interpreters. Anaconda is trash as far as for my experience, just errors nothing useful...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).