# How to use read_gbq or other bq in IPython to access datasets hosted in BigQuery

Tags: ipython, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I am using the iPython notebook to read the Google BigQuery public dataset for natality
I have done the installation for the google-api
`easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client`.

However it still does not detect the installed API

## Anyone has a iPython notebook to share on accessing the public dataset and loading it into a dataframe in iPython.

```
import pandas as pd
projectid = "xxxx"
data_frame = pd.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM xxxx', project_id = projectid)

    303     if not _GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_INSTALLED:
--> 304         raise ImportError('Could not import Google API Client.')
    305 
    306     if not _GOOGLE_FLAGS_INSTALLED:

ImportError: Could not import Google API Client
```

I have shared the iPython Notebook used at
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/dl.dropbox.com/s/d77u2xarscagw0b/BigQuery_Trial8.ipynb?dl=0

Additional info:
I am running on a server with a docker instance used for the iPython server.
I have run the curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash installation on the linux server

I have tried to run some of the shared notebooks
nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/fhoffa/6459195
or nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/fhoffa/6472099
However I also get 
         ImportError: No module named bq

I suspect it is a simple case of missing dependencies. 
Anyone who has clues, help welcome

Comment: I don't have an iPython notebook but was able to reproduce your error and fix it. If you look into lines 27-35 from https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/gbq.py there are some imports which could fail. Could you try them one by one?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I need to digest it a bit more. Still seems like I have a few imports missing.

Answer (score 1):

As I just said it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31708375/2533394
I solved the problem with this:

```
pip install --force-reinstall uritemplate.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Pandas is version 0.17 or higher:

`pip install -U pandas`

You can check with:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```