# Unresolved reference 'build' - YouTube Python API

Tags: python, youtube

I'm fairly new to Python so this maybe really simple. I'm wanting to use the YouTube API to pull my latest YouTube videos. The problem is Python isn't allowing me to do so. I'm running Python version 2.7.6

I've used pip to install the Google dependencies:

```
$ pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

To no avail, I'm still getting the following problem:

```
Unresolved reference 'build'
```

The code I'm using is: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#retrieve_my_uploads

I'm wondering if anybody has come across this. I'm using PyCharm as my IDE for OS X. I've searched and searched and can't find a solution. I've tried Python versions: `2.6.9, 2.7.6, 3.4.2`

I'd really appreciate some advice.

Comment: Python API client was successfully installed and when you try to import it in PyCharm (something like `from apiclient.discovery import build`) you get trace, right?

Comment: @Andersson I got logged out and couldn't log back in, but here's the traceback I'm getting: http://pastebin.com/PUDtmkvk

Comment: but this is totally different issue

Comment: I don't understand why this just isn't working. All I've done is followed the instructions from the YouTube API.

Comment: If you can not re-log in to your account, try to re-open new Question with part of code you already have wrote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267749/importerror-no-module-named-apiclient-discovery)

Answer (score 8):

Checkout the following answer : 
[ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267749/importerror-no-module-named-apiclient-discovery)

apiclient was the original name of the library.

At some point, it was switched over to be googleapiclient.

```
# bad
from apiclient.discovery import build

# good
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```