# Error while using google-api-python-client

Tags: google-api, anaconda

I am using Anaconda and error come when using google-api-python-client.

Error:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
ImportError: No module named discovery
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267749/importerror-no-module-named-apiclient-discovery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35982655/python-install-module-apiclient. Infact, just googling your error msg gives you loads of potential solutions.

Comment: I tried these things before but error not resolve.
I am using Anaconda, so pip command is not working there.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried `sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

**But it didn't worked for me**.
Then I tried

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

instead of

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
```

**It worked for me**. Hope it helps.