# ImportError: cannot import name discovery

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I am using Google's python API client, and one of the lines it wants you to use is:

```
from apiclient import discovery
```

When I run this it returns the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name discovery

Note: the `apiclient` module is installed and up to date

Thanks guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267749/importerror-no-module-named-apiclient-discovery)

Comment: @fredtantini but then I don't know how to implement that change into my code [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) is the whole google python api client code i used

Answer (score 11):

At some point apiclient module name was changed. If you cannot import discovery from apiclient, then try:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually `apiclient` is an alias for `googleapiclient` in the latest implementations. So, this answer didn't change anything for me. Until I used the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064844/1115187 (which is downvoted without a real reason)

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to get these dependencies with this simple install:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23521799/1115187

Comment: You just copied this from `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267749/importerror-no-module-named-apiclient-discovery` but it's not even the same question.

Comment: actually, this answer **solved** my problem. And the chosen one — no.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I still have the same error even though my libraries are up to date

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

I got the answer from this link: [python install module apiclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35982655/python-install-module-apiclient)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue after seeing the error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient'," which prompted me to install apiclient via pip. After realizing this was probably the wrong library, I then instead installed google-api-python-client via conda, which resolved the error message.

(It looks like you were using google-api-python-client all along, but I wanted to share this in case anyone else was also trying to use the apiclient library on pip to execute google-api-python-client tasks.)