# No module named apiclient.discovery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-client

I got this error in Google App Engine's Python, But I don't know how to fix,

I added into my project directory the following folders:

apiclient, gflags, httplib2, oauth2client, uritemplate

but I got always the same error

Comment: Probably this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267749/importerror-no-module-named-apiclient-discovery

Comment: If the solution provided by @KonstantinosG has helped you, please post it as the answer to this question as a reference to the rest of the community.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267749/importerror-no-module-named-apiclient-discovery)

Answer (score 0):

*This is a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) post of [Jorvis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267749/importerror-no-module-named-apiclient-discovery)*

The [apiclient.discovery](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/discovery/v1) service is a part of the [Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/). You can therefore install the Client Library using the provided command (e.g for Python):

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

This will solve the '*No module named* ...' warning for any of the [supported APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/).

Comment: Do not duplicate answers (even as CW). If that answer answers this question, then this question should be flagged/voted for closure as a duplicate.