# Having trouble importing modules from google app engine with Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine-python

I am writing an app on Eclipse using PyDev and my goal is to deploy it on the Google App Engine. I am trying to run the code found here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api but I am getting an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexballack13/Documents/workspace/BigQuery2/src/query.py", line 8, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 57, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/errors.py", line 31, in <module>
    from oauth2client import _helpers as util
ImportError: cannot import name _helpers
```

I tried doing what others have suggested like: [ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267749/importerror-no-module-named-apiclient-discovery), but still not successful. Has anyone had trouble with "name _helpers"?

Comment: I recently came across the same error, did you find what was causing this issue ?

Comment: I know that your question was for Eclipse, but for me, the solution was to remove the pref folder created by Pycharm `rm -rf .idea`. I have no idea why, but it works...