# Virtual Environment for Python on mac error with Google API Client?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I created a virtual environment on my Desktop called project_env. I then installed the Google API Python Client from github (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client). Then created a Python file called youtube.py with the following code. When I run the file I get "ImportError no module googleapiclient"

```
  from googleapiclient.discovery import build

  api_key = "My Key"

  youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKeys=api_key)

  request = youtube.channels().list(
   part='statistics',
  forUsername='livelifetothefull'
  )

 response = request.execute()
  print(response)
```

I'm very new to this, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been great if you had provided details on how you are running it and what version of `Python` you are using. Without that, I have provided solutions that applies in a general context.

1. You may need to add your `venv` to your path so that it can recognize the site-packages. See [here](https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/venv-win.html) on how you can do that.
2. It may also mean that the interpreter may not be resolving to the correct `venv`. For example, if you running through cmd line try running it with `python3` if you doing with `python` or vice-versa.
3. Change of library issue, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30811628/6505847) on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these commands :

```
cd project_env
source bin/activate
bin/pip install wheel
bin/pip install google-api-python-client
bin/python -c "from googleapiclient.discovery import build"
```