# from apiclient.discovery import build ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient.discovery'

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to use the python `google-api-python-client` for a Youtube Data API project but when I run the following line:

```py
from apiclient.discovery import build
```

I get the following eror:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient.discovery'
```

`import apiclient` runs fine but importing discovery returns an error.

I already checked the top answers from [ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267749/importerror-no-module-named-apiclient-discovery), but to no avail.

When I run `python --version`:
I get `Python 3.7.6`

---

I'm running MacOs Catalina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind I fixed the issue by switching `apiclient` with `googleapiclient`

Answer (score 0):

you really should be using googleapiclient in your code, since the apiclient alias was just maintained as to not break legacy code.

#### incorrect method

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
```

#### correct method

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

Comment: FYI: `googleapiclient` is from the [`google-api-python-client`](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/) package.