# Google app engine problems regarding import library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

I am thinking about doing some test on app engine. And I have read about the library google has originally provided. I wonder what should I do if I want to use some external libraries that were installed before as part of Python2.7 such as Pyaudio and wx..
   I was aware of that I should claim the library in the yaml file but what else do I need to do? Will naming and assigning a new environment variable help? If it does help, what paths should I include here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should read up on the python sandbox and runtime restrictions, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_sandbox

This tells you how to use other libraries.

The libraries you list can not be used in appengine.

Also read up on 3rd party libraries that are directly supported https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Comment: Thanks.I am a newbie in this area. Is there any other way to make web application using framework like the one Google has provided?

Comment: @user3214914 In case you want to include the 3rd party libraries that could be used on App Engine here a more detailed answer on how to do that.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14851686/8418