# Importing 3rd Party Libraries in GAE (not manually) using Pip or another tool

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way to import 3rd party libraries to GAE in a way that is not manual?

i.e. **not** the solution mentioned here: 
[How to include third party Python libraries in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libs-in-google-appengine)

The ideal would be to `pip install -r requirements.txt` into a virtualenv, then somehow make that library available in the local GAE development server, and of course on GAE itself.

Comment: have you tried this? http://blog.altlimit.com/2013/06/google-app-engine-virtualenv-tool-that.html I created this for this exact purpose. It should work with virtualenv, just run the bin/gaenv from the virtualenv that you are using to create the symlinks found on requirements.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using pip and virtualenv, you need to create symlinks from `./lib/python2.7/site-packages/"libxxx"` to your GAE project directory (where `.` is the root of your virtualenv directory, and `libxxx` is the name of the 3rd party library you're willing to install).

If there are symbolic links in your GAE project, then `appcfg.py` will resolve these links when publishing your app on Google's infrastructure.

For example, on Mac OS X, to install HTTPlib on GAE, I did the following:

```
ln -s ~/Projets/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/ ~/Projets/myproject/src/packages/libs/httplib2/
```

After that, provided your code is somewhere inside `~/Projets/myproject/src`, you can use the library using: `from packages.libs import httplib2`.

Comment: would that mean that you'd need to `pip install -d ~/myproject <package>`? Because when I use the regular `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside of an virtualenv, it doesn't install into `~/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

Comment: No, do not change your `pip install` directory, it would break your existing setup. The initial packages location is not really relevant. Wherever your virtualenv is located, you need to symlink the packages from `/path/to/your/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"libxxx"` to a subdirectory of your GAE project (it doesn't even need to be `/src/packages/libs` like in my answer, it's just a common way of organizing GAE projects).

Comment: In fact your virtualenv does not need to share a common root directory with your GAE project, but I like keeping them at the same location, in case I want to build another project with other Python libs.