# Is it possible to run scikit-learn on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get scikit-learn to run on Google App Engine. Since scikit-learn isn't one of [the default included libraries in GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27), I followed the instructions [from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/) but I couldn't get it to work. I suspected the problem has something to do with dependencies, so in desperation I found out [scikit-learn's dependencies](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) and added numpy and setuptolls inapp.yaml and scipy in the "libs" folder. Unsurprisingly, this didn't work either.

So, I have to ask, is what I'm attempting to do even possible or should I try using a different framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Python 3.7 Standard Runtime supports importation of any libraries you want to use, such as `sklearn`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/appengine-generation)

Answer (score 3):

scikit-learn is a complicated library with many 'c' based dependencies. Read on a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169106/unable-to-use-tfidfvectorizer-in-google-app-engine).