# unable to use TfidfVectorizer in Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scikit-learn

I am writing a python program in Google App Engine that calculates tf-idf using TfidfVectorizer in sklearn.

I have added sklearn library and have the import as:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
```

However it gives me `no module named _check_build` although it is in the library that I have imported.

Note: I have the same code in pure python and it works just fine so there is nothing wrong with the python syntax or imports; The problem starts with GAE.

Do you know any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not using any of GAE-specific tools, try deploying your app on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).
It let's you deploy a whole virtual environment with all the installed libraries on it. Specifically, Scikit-learn works on Heroku just fine. Check [this Github repo](https://github.com/everysignalinc/heroku-buildpack-python-scikit-learn-git) for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  sklearn has a lot of 'c' based dependencies and typically any module that is named with a leading `_` is a binary module.

So that's why you are getting a no `module named _check_build` error.

I seriously doubt you will get it to run even if you fake some of the 'c' libs unless they have pure python analogues.

I have done this in the past where libs had 'c' based performance versions as well as pure python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but do you know of a python  library that I can use for tf-idf on Google App Engine ?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what it does. You would be better off running this under GCE or EC2.  When managed vm's are in general release then you can revisit appengine.