# scikit learn on google cloud platform through datalab or compute engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, scikit-learn, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datalab

I am running a Django App inside GCP. My idea was to call a python script from "view.py" for some machine learning algorithm and then display the result on the page.

But now I understand that running a machine learning library like Scikit-learn on GAE will not be possible (read Tim's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169106/unable-to-use-tfidfvectorizer-in-google-app-engine) and [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6273)).

**But suppose I need to still do this, I believe there are 2 ways possible, but I am not sure weather my guess is right or wrong**

1) As the **Google-Datalab** provides the entire anaconda like distribution, if we have any **datalab api** which can be called from a python file in the Django app, I can achieve my goal ?

2) If I can **install** the **scikit-learn library on any compute engine** on GCP and somehow send it the request to run my code and then return the output back to the python file in the Django app ?

I am very new to client-server and cloud computing on the whole, so please provide examples (if possible) for any suggestion/ pointer for the help.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is to use the [App Engine Flex environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) rather than the standard App Engine environment.

App Engine Flex uses a compute engine VM for running your code, so it does not have the library limitations that standard App Engine has.

Specifically, you'll need to add a ['requirements.txt' file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries) to specify the version of scikit-learn that you want installed, and then add a ['vm: true' clause to your app.yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml).

Answer (score 0):

sklearn is now supported on ML Engine.

So, another alternative now is to use online prediction on Cloud ML Engine, and deploy your scikit-learn model as a web service.

Here is a fully worked out example of using fully-managed scikit-learn training, online prediction and hyperparameter tuning:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/blogs/sklearn/babyweight_skl.ipynb