# Using Scikit-learn google app engine

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, scikit-learn

I am trying to deploy a python2.7 application on google app engine. It uses few modules like numpy,flask,pandas and scikit-learn. Though I am able to install and use other modules. Installing scikit-learn in lib folder of project give following error:-

**Traceback (most recent call last): File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler()) File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler) File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject obj = __import__(path[0]) File "/base/data/home/apps/s~category-prediction-1247/v1.391344087004233892/deploynew.py", line 6, in  import sklearn File "/base/data/home/apps/s~category-prediction-1247/v1.391344087004233892/lib/sklearn/__init__.py", line 56, in  from . import __check_build File "/base/data/home/apps/s~category-prediction-1247/v1.391344087004233892/lib/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 46, in  raise_build_error(e) File "/base/data/home/apps/s~category-prediction-1247/v1.391344087004233892/lib/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 41, in raise_build_error %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg)) ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_check_build) ___________________________________________________________________________ Contents of /base/data/home/apps/s~category-prediction-1247/v1.391344087004233892/lib/sklearn/__check_build: setup.pyc __init__.py _check_build.so setup.py __init__.pyc ___________________________________________________________________________ It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly. If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or `make` in the source directory. If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your Python version, your operating system and your platform.**

Is their any way of using scikit-learn on google app engine?

Comment: This error is comming on App engine. I was able to install Scikit-learn succesfully using **pip install -t lib scikit-learn** in lib folder of the repository i am deploying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like sci-kit learn is not supported on App Engine's Standard environment for Python 2.x, and the using managed VMs is the preferred solution in this case. See the resolution of [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6273).

Also see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763165/is-it-possible-to-run-scikit-learn-on-google-app-engine) for another alternative approach.

Answer (score 3):

Scikit-learn can now be used on App Engine Flexible Environment.

`sklearn` just needs to be specified as a dependency in the `requirements.txt` file.

See this [repo](https://github.com/syltruong/sklearn-gae-sample/blob/master/README.md) for a code sample on how to serve a `sklearn` model on App Engine.

Comment: I'd imagine that it can now be used in the new Appengine Standard Python3.7 environment too, as like flex it doesn't have the sandbox restrictions of traditional App Engine.

Comment: I have not tested it yet. It would be interesting to see. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

The newly-released 2nd Generation Python 3.7 Standard Environment (experimental) can run all modules. It's still in beta, though.