# Blank Page with web.py and Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web.py

I'm trying to get web.py app running on local Google App Engine.

My yaml:

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: code.app
```

My code.py:

```
import web

urls = (
    "/.*", "hello",
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return 'Hello, world!'

app = app.gaerun()
```

When I start the server all I get is a blank page. So what's wrong?

Edit:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Edit 2:

Error from console:

```
ImportError: No module named web
```

Comment: you have to give more info.. most likely you are getting some errors in the console.. can you provide those?

Comment: @Lipis please see edit2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is import an external module, which is not supported by GAE.

What you can do though, is copy web.py into your app directory, and then use it. See ["How to include third party Python libraries in Google App Engine"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14851686/8418).

You can get the source code from [here](https://github.com/webpy/webpy)