# Jinja 2 filesize formatter

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I have Jinja2 2.7.3 installed and trying to render a list of files with their filesize.

When I use just the parameter vale I get:

```
#using {{fs}}

22528
23786
9769
```

If I apply the filesizeformatter the outputs are 0

```
#using {{fs|filesizeformat}}

0.0 kB
0.0 kB
0.0 kB
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Template is as follow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FileBrowser</title>
  </head>
<body>

<form action="/admin/filemanager" method="post">
    <TABLE>
        <TR>
            <TD>File</TD>
            <TD>Size</TD>
            <TD>Size formatted</TD>
        </TR>

       {% for f in files %}
       <TR>
           <TD>{{f[0]}}</TD>
           <td>{{f[1]}}</td>
           <TD>{{f[1]|filesizeformat}}</TD>
       </TR>
       {% endfor %}
    </TABLE>

    <input name = "import" type="submit" value="Importar" />
    <input name = "delete" type="submit" value="Borrar" />

</form>
```

The call is made by:

```
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_environment.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class view(Handler):
     def get(self):
        files=[['hello.txt',23221],['foo.txt',21211]]
        self.render('FileBrowser.html', files=files)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@davidisn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400617/davidism) I was able to notice that the installed version of Jinja2 in the GAE SDK (and production) is 2.6

Jinja 2.6 had a bug in the fileformatter that was fixed in [2.7](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/changelog/)

Just installed manually the library in the [lib folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libraries-in-google-app-engine) of my project and everything worked as supposed.

Hope some one find this helpful

Answer (score 1):

Jinja had a [bug with filesizeformat](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/pull/59) until version 2.7.  GAE uses Jinja-2.6 by default, so you'll need to upgrade to a newer version.