# Using gspread in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, setup.py, gspread

I am unable to get a Python package, [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread), to work in GAE.

My project is in `D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp`. I installed `gspread` using:

```
c:\python27\python.exe setup.py install --home="D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp"
```

All the files appear to be installed in `D:\Documents\Google Cloud\myapp\lib\python` without offering me a choice.  In fact, I have to add this path to `PYTHONPATH` in order for setup.py to run properly.

If I then run Python, I can `import gspread` in the interpreter.

However, in myapp, I can't import (`ImportError: No module named gspread`) even when I added that long path to `sys.path`.  My `sys.path` at run-time contains, among other values,:

```
'D:\\Documents\\Google Cloud\\myapp\\lib\\python'
'D:\\Documents\\Google Cloud\\myapp'
'D:\\Documents\\Google Cloud\\myapp\\lib'
```

What is needed to get this third party module to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include third party Python libraries in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libraries-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: Yes, I did see that, but couldn't find anything that's applicable. My module is not in source form but added via setup.py. I have no time to go into the details of how setup.py works.

Comment: It's all applicable. I know how setup.py works.   re-read the answer it is right there for you `import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')`  . Notice the similiarity between hello/libs in the answer and your structure.  You need to realize the dev server is emulating the production sandbox and won't user fully qualified paths.

Comment: The on thing I wouldn't do is include the path in the top of your app. Use app_config.py to set things up like global paths as this is loaded before any of your code.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the above is still running on my local machine, not deployed to Google yet. I did sys.path.insert, and other than the first path in `sys.path` which I added manually, the others are all included by the GAE Launcher.  In the `...lib\path` folder, there is a `gspread-0.2.5-py2.7.egg` file among others.  Is `...lib\python` the correct value that must in `sys.path` for `gspread` to be located?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding the following, path of a **file** and not a folder, to `sys.path`:

```
D:\Documents\Google Cloud\Drive-1185\lib\python\gspread-0.2.5-py2.7.egg
```

A relative path may be used as the working directory is the app directory. To deploy to Google's servers, obviously only a relative path can be used, and not only that, backward slashes must be replaced with forward slashes.