# "ImportError: cannot import name OSRNG" when importing gcloud.storage in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have installed gcloud on my machine and it works correctly.

When deploying to Google App Engine, I install all requirements to lib (`pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include third party Python libraries in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libraries-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: With the caveat that some third party libraries are pre-installed in Google App Engine and we must simply specify as such in app.yaml, and also that information that pycrypto is needed is nowhere.

Comment: Except most of the 3rd party libs supported in in app.yaml are not included in the SDK which means you have to install them locally, but you do not deploy them with your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `pycrypto` to your `libraries` in `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "latest"
```