# Cannot import datastore module in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to deploy a simple python Flask app to appengine which makes use of Google Datastore.

The problem is I cannot import the datastore library. The server gives a 500 error and the log says -

`ImportError: cannot import name datastore`

My import statement looks like this -

```
from google.cloud import datastore
```

I've tried packaging it in with the app inside the `lib/` folder like a 3rd party library (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libraries-in-google-app-engine)) but that didn't help either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include third party Python libraries in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libraries-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: @JeffO'Neill - No I tried packaging the library in but that didn't work either.