# Google App Engine ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, boto

I am creating a Python Web App in Google App engine.
When I

> sudo pip install

a third party library and then try to import it, I get the error 'ImportError: No module named x'. Where x is the name of that library. In my case as an example: Boto, Boto3, Fask  etc.

If I go into shell in GAE and type python >> import X the library can be used inside the python environment. When deploying the app though or running the app in the virtaul server in Google App Engine I get the module import error.

- I even tried methods like: python >> import sys >> sys.path.insert(0, "path_here")
- export PYTHONPATH and selected where those libraries are located

I even followed several Q&A here in Stackoverflow without any success, can somebody please give me a proper way to fix the import error in Google App Engine?

### FYI

- I am not using any local environment in my pc, I am working directly through the GAE bash console, the launch code editor in GAE and I am running the command dev_appserver.py $PWD
- When I do

> pip freeze

I can see that the modules are currently installed and deployed on the GAE virtual environment. Is there a problem with my path? What's the best approach to make GAE load my already installed third party libraries.

UPDATE:
Importing the library directly on the python shell from Google App Engine works just fine. Importing the library on my python app index.py file results in the error. 
[Python import directly from Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvozY.png)
[Python import to the index.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdP4J.png)

Comment: Are you using GAE standard og GAE flexible environment?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your question. Where can I determine if it is a standard or a flexible environment?

Comment: That is a selection you do when you create the app. Eg have a look in https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?project=[your project id] . Reason for asking is that handling of external libraies are different. For GAE standard use of external libraries are limited. What library are you trying to include?

Comment: I am trying to import boto, boto3 and some other third party libraries for the deployment of charts. At the moment it is a standard environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include third party Python libraries in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libraries-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: If you check above the 'UPDATE' section I included two images. I already did what it is said in that post with no luck. How can I move from a standard environment to a flexible one without starting a new project from scratch?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating

Comment: not much of help. Do you have direct instructions like step by step? Because what it is written on that particular page doesn't seem to help much.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old thread, adding this answer now:

Run command : gcloud components list

This will show the different components installed and not in your environment.

Install app-engine-python components if not installed:

> gcloud components install app-engine-python
>
> gcloud components install app-engine-python-extras

If it doesn't work:

In Windows, uninstall and download and install Google-sdk (check the python version you need). Delete all the files the installer ask you to delete in the last step and run the gcloud component commands again.