# How to install and use Beautiful Soup with Python in Google App Engine successfully?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup, lxml

I've tried many times to install and use Beautiful Soup "3.2.1" with Python "2.7" in Google App Engine, but unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the mentioned steps successfully.

I followed the instructions in the link below:
[Python 2.7 : How to use BeautifulSoup in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638262/python-2-7-how-to-use-beautifulsoup-in-google-app-engine/14648038#14648038)

I tried to run BeautifulSoupTests.py and I got many errors, meaning that there is something wrong. See the errors below:

> 500 Uncaught exception Traceback (most recent call last):
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~andrevgm-bliss/playground.372749155112263262/mimic/mimic_wsgi.py
>   line 51 in **iter** access_key=access_key)
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~andrevgm-bliss/playground.372749155112263262/mimic/**mimic/mimic.py
>   line 400 in RunMimic RunTargetApp(tree, path_info, namespace,
>   users_mod)
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~andrevgm-bliss/playground.372749155112263262/mimic/__mimic/mimic.py
>   line 228 in RunTargetApp ServeScriptPage(tree, config, page,
>   namespace)
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~andrevgm-bliss/playground.372749155112263262/mimic/__mimic/mimic.py
>   line 123 in ServeScriptPage env.RunScript(page.script_path,
>   control.LoggingHandler(namespace))
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~andrevgm-bliss/playground.372749155112263262/mimic/__mimic/target_env.py
>   line 983 in RunScript raise TargetAppError(formatted_exception)
>   TargetAppError: Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~andrevgm-bliss/playground.372749155112263262/mimic/__mimic/target_env.py",
>   line 968, in RunScript loader.load_module('__main**') File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~andrevgm-bliss/playground.372749155112263262/mimic/**mimic/target_env.py",
>   line 316, in load_module return self.env.LoadModule(self, fullname)
>   File
>   "/base/data/home/apps/s~andrevgm-bliss/playground.372749155112263262/mimic/__mimic/target_env.py",
>   line 725, in LoadModule exec(code, module.__dict**) # pylint:
>   disable-msg=W0122 File "BeautifulSoupTests.py", line 908, in 
>   unittest.main() File
>   "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py",
>   line 95, in **init** self.runTests() File
>   "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py",
>   line 234, in runTests sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
>   SystemExit: True

Comment: For some reason you are trying to run the unittests.   You will need to show us how you are calling Beautiful soup.  As it runs fine in appengine.

Comment: Follow the project that I'm trying to run into app engine. Please, download my project from my google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B83hLNyHZ5eBbXdERy1CNjR4SEk/edit?usp=sharing