# Google app engine error ImportError: No module named bccache

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

When trying to run my Google App Engine app, I get the following error:

```
 (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:263)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/p~mygoolgeappproject/3.402458165629390060/village/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import flask
  File "/base/data/home/apps/p~mygoolgeappproject/3.402458165629390060/libs/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
  File "/base/data/home/apps/p~mygoolgeappproject/3.402458165629390060/libs/jinja2/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from jinja2.bccache import BytecodeCache, FileSystemBytecodeCache, \
ImportError: No module named bccache
```

Comment: This looks a sloppy paste of an error message/call stack trace (try using a "block quote"): What question is this community supposed to answer? See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear whether you're using App Engine Standard or App Engine Flexible environment. I'm taking a guess that it is App Engine Standard and posting this answer.

App Engine Standard has only a limited set of libraries available in the runtime environment. If you need to add any third-party libraries, you will need to add them manually by following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27).

You can also look at these answers for more info.

- [How to include third party Python libraries in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14851686/380757)
- [Python 2.7 : How to use BeautifulSoup in Google App Engine? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648038/380757)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, It is the problem that some of the libraries wasn't installed correctly like Jinja2 etc.
I reinstalled it and it worked.